# How to get histogram average per param

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I've got the following histogram metric `db_query_duration_ms_sum` (it's histogram so I've got `_sum`, `_count` and `_bucket`).

`db_query_duration_ms_sum` has a param `query_name` which is the name of a db query.

How do I create a bar gauge which displays the average duration per query name? Something like:
[image]

As you can see, I'm pretty close. I'm trying to calculate it using:

```
sum(rate(db_query_duration_ms_sum{}[$__rate_interval])) by (query_name) / 
sum(rate(db_query_duration_ms_count{}[$__rate_interval])) by (query_name)
```

However, there are 2 issues:

1. The above is returning a bunch of `NaN`. Within the bar gauge grafana options, I've selected "Value options/Calculation" to be `Last (last non-null value)` but that doesn't seem to make a difference. **I want to display the average duration per each query within the selected timeframe**.
2. The rows in the bar gauge are not sorted. How do I sort them in desc order? I tried wrapping my query with `sort_desc` but yet again, that doesn't do anything. **How do I sort the rows?**

Comment: If you want "average duration per each query within the selected timeframe", you should use `increase(... [$__interval])` instead of `rate(... [$__rate_interval])`.

Comment: thanks @markalex. Do you mind explaining why that is? What does my current query give?

Comment: Oops, comment to early in the morning. `$__range` is correct variable, not `$__interval`

Comment: I have tried: `sum(increase(...[$__range])) by (query_name) / 
sum(increase(...[$__range])) by (query_name)` but it's still resulting in a lot of NaN values even though I've set "Last (last non-null value)". Probably because of division with 0.

Comment: `increase(... [$__range])` calculates increase of your metric within time between `from` and `to` times of your dashboard. So if your dashboard time range is [now-1h, now], you'll get increase over last ` hour. `rate(... [$__rate_interval])` shows increase over `$__rate_interval` (=~ 4*scrape_interval, default 1m).

Comment: Notice also, that `rate(... [$__rate_interval])` will be correctly used, if you'd use graph panel. Rate estimates per-second increase of counter, and is not intended for use over long ranges.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting `Nan`. IIRC, Grafana shows symbol of infinity, if we divide by 0. Check what is shown in table veiw (toggle on top, when editing panel)

Comment: Table view shows the same (NaN). Also, do you have any suggestions on how I can sort the bar chart, so the slowest query is on top and the fastest in the bottom?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254375/discussion-between-martin-and-markalex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are getting `Nan`s in your data, but to avoid `Inf`s (due to number of requests being 0), you can use this query:

```
sum(increase(db_query_duration_ms_sum [$__range])) by (query_name)
     / sum(increase(db_query_duration_ms_count[$__range])) by (query_name) < +Inf
  or sum(increase(db_query_duration_ms_count[$__range])) by (query_name)
```

It filters out values of infinity, and if the appear - replaces them with zeros.

And if you don't want zeros and prefer them to be missing - omit everything beginning with `or`.

---

Based on OP's report, same query filters out `Nan`s too. But since I cannot explain why it happened in the first place, I cannot explain how it helped too.